# Given a mercurial changeset, how do I go back to before that changeset?

Tags: mercurial

We are using Mercurial. I think there is a problem with a changeset. To make sure, I want to go back to the state before that changeset.

How do i do that ?

Comment: `hg help revsets` is always-useful reading

Comment: @Lazy Badger Wow... `hg help revsets` is very very useful.... There's a lot of operations described there that I wanted to do and couldn't find documentation for... Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `hg up {REVISION}~1` to update your working copy to the state before the problematic changeset.

When you don't already have published the changeset, you can use [`hg strip`](https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension) to remove the changeset (warning: strip is a destructive operation).

If the changeset is already published, you can use [`hg backout`](https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Backout) at the top of the branch to get mercurial to reverse-apply the changes of the problematic changeset.